# How can I check whether session was timed out?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

How can I check in an error page whether the session was timed out?

I have tried

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty pageContext.request.session}">
        //do smth
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        //do smth
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no **reliable** way to detect that. You could fiddle with some session based token as request parameter in all links/forms and validate it in the filter, but that's fully spoofable and not really SEO friendly.

Best what you could do is to add a `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` tag to the `<head>` of the master template which redirects the page to the session timeout error page *automatically* whenever the session is expired. Since you're using a shared error page, you could pass the condition as a request parameter:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval};url=error.jsp?type=timeout" />
```

and check it in the `error.jsp` as follows:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${param.type == 'timeout'}">
        <p>Your session has been timed out.</p>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <!-- Handle default case here. -->
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Oh, yes, `${pageContext.session}` is legitimately valid. The `${pageContext.request.session}` is just an unnecessary detour. Check the [`PageContext` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html) for all available getters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work the way you want.  try ${pageContext.request.session.new}

If you don't specify in the <%@page session="false"%> tag I don't think it creates a new session so your first code /might/ work but I would stress checking in the fashion I indicated above.

.isNew() is defined on HttpSession

Comment: it doesn't work neither with session="false" nor with session.new
Actually I want the user to see a message about session has been timed out while browsing the links after a period of time. But also I use this page to inform users that they have not access to some resources(I redirect from filter to this page). And so I use such construction to check the session timed out to give different messages

Answer (score 0):

request.getSession() will always return session, thus your approach will not work. If your requirement is not create a session, when does not exist, use a custom tag.

If you want to create a session when it does not exist, and you want to know if the the request is joining the session/creating a new session. Use ${pageContext.request.session.new}.